# How do I make h5py MPI-aware with the apt package system?

Tags: apt, 16.04, kubuntu, python, mpi

As I am trying to run parallel hdf5 with h5py and mpi4py, I am met with the following error:

```
 NameError: global name 'mpi4py' is not defined
```

Googling suggests that this is because h5py is not "mpi-aware" and suggests recompiling.  I would like to do this within the package system, such that I can update packages safely, etc.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: How did you install `mpi4py`?

Comment: Like this:   sudo apt-get install python-mpi4py

Comment: You are using Python 2 I assume?

Comment: I tried with both 2 and 3.  The difference is that python3 will not say "global" in front of name in the error message.